# Mic on SENNHEISER HD 450BT intermittently disconnects

Tags: zoom-sdk

I have Sennheiser HD 450BT, that overall works great, but when on zoom call, mic intermittently disconnects/mute.

Anyone experienced something similar?

The only way to recover, disconnect and reconnect to computer.

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is off-topic here, and the tag [zoom-sdk] is only for coding problems. Maybe you can ask on SuperUser